# Is ctags support fixed prototype function of GCC?

Tags: gcc, vim, ctags

I found that gcc support a strange function definition like:

```
static void add_define P3(char *, name, int, nargs, char *, exps)
```

Which compile with -D__USE_FIXED_PROTOTYPES__. And my taglist plugins of vim couldn't give correct result. I tried to figure out in man page of ctags but I couldn't find it.

**EDIT**
Yes, this is strange. The macro is

```
#define P3(t1, v1, t2, v2, t3, v3) (t1 v1, t2 v2, t3 v3)
```

and the comment tells that this is

> ANSI/K&R compatibility stuff.

It's intend to suite xlc, the c compiler of AIX.

Comment: Odd declaration; `name`, `nargs`, `exps` are type names?  Or do you have stray commas separating names from types somehow?  Where is P3 defined?  How is it defined?  Is the semicolon missing from the end?  However, C is hard enough to understand without trying to make `ctags` support that sort of notation.  You need most of a compiler to get that to work.  Why do you think that the P3 macro is still beneficial?  Why not write the code as a genuine regular function?  Which compiler does not support standard prototype notations?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler `name`, `nargs`, `exps` are variable names. Maybe you're right, I should replace this hell thing into regular function before reading it.

Comment: I see now why it is `P3`; it is for a prototype with 3 arguments.  Time to get rid of the notation, I think.  Certainly, AIX (xlc) does not require the alternative notation — the non-prototype form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the macro definition as shown:

```
#define P3(t1, v1, t2, v2, t3, v3) (t1 v1, t2 v2, t3 v3)
```

this declaration:

```
static void add_define P3(char *, name, int, nargs, char *, exps);
```

(I've added a trailing semicolon) expands to this:

```
static void add_define(char *name, int nargs, char *exps);
```

which is a perfectly ordinary function prototype (assuming a trailing semicolon).

There's probably an alternate version of that macro, something like this:

```
#define P3(t1, v1, t2, v2, t3, v3) \
    (v1, v2, v3) \
    t1 v1; \
    t2 v2; \
    t3 v3;
```

that would expand to:

```
static void add_define(name, nargs, exps)
char *name;
int nargs;
char *exps
```

which is a K&R-style non-prototype function declaration.

Likely there's something like:

```
#ifdef __STDC__
#define P3(t1, v1, t2, v2, t3, v3) (t1 v1, t2 v2, t3 v3)
#else
#define P3(t1, v1, t2, v2, t3, v3) \
    (v1, v2, v3) \
    t1 v1; \
    t2 v2; \
    t3 v3;
#endif
```

along with similar macros P0, P1, P2, etc., for different numbers of parameters.  Or perhaps, as you imply in your question, it uses a user-defined macro `__USE_FIXED_PROTOTYPES__` rather than `__STDC__`.

This would allow a single declaration to automatically expand either to a modern prototype or to a K&R-style declaration; the latter would be necessary only with very old pre-ANSI compilers.

To answer the question in the title (finally!), `ctags` operates on non-preprocessed C source. A quick experiment with the GNU `ctags` shows that it's not particularly clever about interpreting macros that obscure the basic syntax. It will generate tag entries for the macro definitions themselves, but it won't recognize

```
static void add_define P3(char *, name, int, nargs, char *, exps) {
    /* ... */
}
```

as a function definition. (You could run the source file through the preprocessor, but then the tags would refer to the preprocessed file, which is not particularly useful.) In principle, `ctags` *should* understand the complete C syntax, including the preprocessor; in practice, it doesn't.

If you want to have `ctags` generate tags for your source file, you'll need to get rid of the macros and write recognizable prototypes. You  won't be able to compile the modified source with a pre-ANSI compiler, but these days that's very unlikely to be a problem. If you're in a position to do this, the resulting code should be easier to maintain.

Or, since the output generated by `ctags` is reasonably simple, it shouldn't be too difficult to manually add the relevant tags to the `tags` file (though maintaining it automatically could be difficult).

Comment: While this is all true and an explanation of what the P3 macro is for, it doesn't really address his question about `ctags`.

Comment: @KeithThompson Thanks, the explanation of C Macros is impressive.